# Write String after every line in every file of a folder

Tags: python

I am new to Python and want to add a text line after every line of all files (only in specified file extensions) in a root folder and all subfolders with a Python script.
What I collected from the internet:

```
import os
import fnmatch

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("dir"):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith(".x",".y"):
            with open(filename, "r") as f:
                file_lines = [''.join([x.strip(), "some_string", '\n']) for x in f.readlines()]
            with open(filename, "w") as f:
                f.writelines(file_lines)
```

I tested it with a small folder but get the error:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Open the file in `append` mode.

Code -

```
import os


def foo(root, desired_extensions, text_line):
    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(root):
        for f in files:
            file_path = os.path.join(subdir, f)
            file_extension = os.path.splitext(file_path)[1]
            if file_extension in desired_extensions:
                with open(file_path, 'a') as f:
                    f.write(text_line + '\n')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo('/a/b/c/d', {'.txt', '.cpp'}, 'blahblahblah')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you try to access file just by its name - ignoring the path to its location.
You need to use a full path to access the file:  os.path.join(root, filename)

Answer (score 0):

`filename` does not include the path.  You need to create the full path yourself by joining `root` and `filename`.  I would suggest the following:

```
for path, _, files in os.walk("dir"):
    for filename in files:
        if os.path.splitext(filename)[1] in ("x", "y"):
            with open(os.path.join(path, filename)) as file:
                file_lines = ...
            ...
```